# google map markers and line not responsive

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently working on google map (responsive) I searched several option over SO but i couldn't able to reproduce the same where I can able to re-size the map for mobile and tablet But I have markers and path this was not fit center the screen size. And Need to add text inside the marker dynamically I am not at all getting anything.

Here is the code for markers line

CSS

```
#map
{
   height: 83%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top:65px;
   z-index: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;    
}
```

javascript:

```
initMap();

function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
        lat: 51.1500,
        lng: -1.000
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: 'Styles/images/ic_pin_from.png',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.3700, -2.3800)
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: 'Styles/images/ic_pin_to.png',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.1600, 0.1080)
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: 'Styles/images/ic_car.png',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.7200, -0.2800)
});
/*var flightPlanCoordinates = [
{lat: 51.3610, lng: -2.300},
{lat: 51.2680, lng: 0.464}
];*/
var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
    lat: 51.3740,
    lng: -2.300
}, {
    lat: 51.3510,
    lng: -1.1640
}, {
    lat: 51.1600,
    lng: -1.0000
}, {
    lat: 51.8950,
    lng: -0.5000
}];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#00298B',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/vpyuo7fo/5/) for the same

Answer (score 0):

Add the points in the polyline to an empty [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) object with the `.extend` method, then call `map.fitBounds`.

```
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // for each marker do:
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  for (var i=0; i<flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(flightPlanCoordinates[i].lat, flightPlanCoordinates[i].lng));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vpyuo7fo/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
initMap();

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: 51.1500,
      lng: -1.000
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    // icon: 'http://imgur.com/3PFbvd1',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.3700, -2.3800)
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    // icon: 'http://imgur.com/dc2Sq4r',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.1600, 0.1080)
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    // icon: 'Styles/images/ic_car.png',
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.7200, -0.2800)
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
    lat: 51.3740,
    lng: -2.300
  }, {
    lat: 51.3510,
    lng: -1.1640
  }, {
    lat: 51.1600,
    lng: -1.0000
  }, {
    lat: 51.8950,
    lng: -0.5000
  }];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#00298B',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);

  for (var i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(flightPlanCoordinates[i].lat, flightPlanCoordinates[i].lng));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 83%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 65px;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @geocodezip thanks for the reply the marker is not there which i have

Comment: Hi @geocodezio i have updated the fiddle link kindly please check

Answer (score 0):

@mahadhevan, Try with this code.

```
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
       var center = map.getCenter();
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
       map.setCenter(center); 
  });
```